# Multiple versions of Safari on Windows XP?

Tags: jquery, safari, webkit, multiple-browsers

Is there any way to run multiple versions of Safari under Windows XP?
I'm interested in running Safari versions 3.1 and 4.

Specifically, i want to debug this type of problem with Safari 3.1 which does not occur on my current version:

[INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR in jQuery when doing multiple selectors on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770669/invalidnodetypeerr-in-jquery-when-doing-multiple-selectors-on-chrome)

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: while i have no idea if running 2 versions of safari works on XP, (got vista myself) i use a virtual xp to debug many things.
i have firefox 2.x,  IE6, and safari 3.1 installed on a virtual pc instance which i boot to test those 3, while i have firefox 3.5, IE7 and safari 4 on my own pc.

it is my opinion that this is the easiest way to target the most browsers to test in. and these are then only the windows browsers...

Comment: I voted to close the question as a duplicate of [Cross-browser testing: All major browsers on ONE machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/cross-browser-testing-all-major-browsers-on-one-machine). Multiple Safari browsers without a Virtual machine **is possible**, and covered in [section 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/cross-browser-testing-all-major-browsers-on-one-machine#10541484).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [BrowserSeal.BrowserPack](http://www.browserseal.com/?option=com_content&view=article&id=35) is what you need. It includes, among other browsers, Safari 3.23. and 4.0.4

Comment: Worth a look. Has anyone used this?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t look like it. I tried installing [Safari 3.2.3 on Windows XP](http://support.apple.com/downloads/Safari_3_2_3_for_Windows) when Safari 4.0.3 was already installed. The installer refused to run due to a later version of Safari being installed.

So it looks like you’ll need a virtual machine to run another copy of Windows. Microsoft has made available some [Virtual PC images with old versions of Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) on them, and there’s a [free version of Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) that runs on Windows XP Pro, so that might be a good way to go.

On the Mac, Michel Fortin has made some builds of Safari that are equivalent to older versions: see [Multi-Safari](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/).

Comment: Woah, why the vote down? Is there a method to run multiple Safaris on one Windows installation now?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Paul...
Another definitive "no" answer from [Apple's dicussion boards](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1801867)

Comment: When there's the will, there's always a way.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention I found a portable version of Safari 5 online (unofficial, you can google for it), but it didn't work too well. But it is an option for those that want multiple versions w/o having to use a virtual machine.