# CSS rendering between different iOS in Safari

Tags: css, ios, safari

I noticed that there is a difference in CSS rendering between iOS 5.x and iOS 4.x.

I guess the two have different Safari versions.

How can I test both versions on my Desktop Safari ? Do I need to use two different Versions of Safari browsers? (on Windows)

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199234/multiple-versions-of-safari-on-windows-xp

Comment: Indeed it seems to be the same problem. But how can I determine the version of safari in different iOS and the equivalent on windows? (I m on the phone right now so I have limited Internet access)

Comment: Best bet would be to use a CSS Reset - http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Google your smartphone model and version to find the default Safari version installed. On Win, click on the Settings button and About Safari. You can also check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) for mobile browsers compatibility or [QuirksMode's mobile tests](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/)